# PhoneGap: Opening iFrame Links outside the APP

Tags: ios, cordova, iframe, phonegap, inappbrowser

Please help me find a solution I have spend 3 days trying to fix this.

I have a phonegap application with iframe in one of the pages. I used target='_blank' in the iframe to open the link in new window outside the APP but instead it opens in the app replacing the whole APP UI.

Answer (score 2):

Did you used [inappbrowser](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser)

Add the plugin using your CLI **cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-inappbrowser**

Here is an Example:

```
function getDirect() {
            var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open('http://www.google.lk','_system' , 'location=yes');
        }
```

**_system**  :  Opens in the system's web browser.

**_self** :  Opens in the Cordova WebView if the URL is in the white list, otherwise it opens in the InAppBrowser.

**_blank**  :  Opens in the InAppBrowser.